# Error using MERGE in SQL Server (with openquery & linked server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 that will do the following:

1. Create a temporary table
2. Perform an insert based on an (Oracle)
   openquery select to populate the temporary table
3. Merge and update the contents of the temporary table with an existing table

However, upon trying it I'm getting an error, and I'm wondering if I'm actually going about this the correct way.

The procedure is as follows:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SyncHealthMainStudRec]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

create table #SyncHealthMainStudRecTemp(
    [HEALTHMAINSTUDRECIDID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SCHOOLNUMBER] [int] NOT NULL,
    [STUDENTID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [WHOCREATED] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [WHENCREATED] [datetime] NULL,
    [WHOMODIFIED] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [WHENMODIFIED] [datetime] NULL,
    [PSGUID] [varchar](50) NULL,
)

end
begin


insert into #SyncHealthMainStudRecTemp
select * from openquery(psdb, 
'select
    h.healthmainstudrecid,
    h.schoolnumber,
    h.studentid,
    h.whocreated,
    h.whencreated,
    h.whomodified,
    h.whenmodified,
    h.psguid
    FROM PS.HealthMainStudRec H ')

--select * from #SyncHealthMainStudRecTemp

MERGE INTO HealthMainStudRec H
USING #SyncHealthMainStudRecTemp S
ON (H.HealthMainStudRecid = S.HealthMainStudRecid) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(healthmainstudrecid, schoolnumber, studentid, whocreated, whencreated,
                whomodified, whenmodified, psguid, D_LastSynced) 
         VALUES(s.healthmainstudrecid, s.schoolnumber, s.studentid, s.whocreated, s.whencreated,
                s.whomodified, s.whenmodified, s.psguid, getdate())
WHEN MATCHED and (
    isnull(H.whocreated,'') collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS <> isnull(S.whocreated,'') collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS or
    isnull(H.whencreated,'') <> isnull(S.whencreated,'') or
    isnull(H.whomodified,'') collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS <> isnull(S.whomodified,'') collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS or
    isnull(H.whenmodified,'') <> isnull(S.whenmodified,'') or
    isnull(H.psguid,'') <> isnull(s.psguid,'')
)
    THEN UPDATE SET H.whocreated = S.whocreated,
                    H.whencreated = S.whencreated,
                    H.whomodified = S.whomodified,
                    H.whenmodified = S.whenmodified,
                    H.psguid = S.psguid,
                    H.D_LastSynced = getdate();
--OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;

drop table SyncHealthMainStudRecTemp

END
```

And the error I'm currently receiving is:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SyncHealthMainStudRec, Line 38
Invalid column name 'healthmainstudrecid'.
```

The column 'healthmainstudrecid' definitely exists in the target table, but I'm not sure of anyway to confirm which table that's actually referring to (source/target). I can't query the temporary table to determine if it's been created successfully either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: It might also be worth mentioning that in SSMS, this line is underlined red:

```
MERGE INTO HEALTHMAINSTUDREC H
```

With the message:

```
Invalid object name 'HEALTHMAINSTUDREC'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#SyncHealthMainStudRecTemp` has column `HEALTHMAINSTUDRECIDID`, not `healthmainstudrecid`. Notice the double `ID`.

Remove `end begin` before `insert into #SyncHealthMainStudRecTemp`.

```
MERGE INTO HealthMainStudRec H
USING #SyncHealthMainStudRecTemp S
ON (H.HealthMainStudRecid = S.HEALTHMAINSTUDRECIDID) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(healthmainstudrecid, schoolnumber, studentid, whocreated, whencreated,
                whomodified, whenmodified, psguid, D_LastSynced) 
         VALUES(s.HEALTHMAINSTUDRECIDID, s.schoolnumber, s.studentid, s.whocreated, s.whencreated,
                s.whomodified, s.whenmodified, s.psguid, getdate())
```

EDIT:

Man you have CASE SENSITIVE collation: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`. So you need to preserve Table names and column names as they are declared.
If table has column HEALTHMAINSTUDRECIDID you will not be able to call it as HealthMainStudRecid when you have case sensitive collation.

Comment: Argh! Thank you, stupid error. I've fixed all the double `ID`s, however I'm still receiving this error:

 `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SyncHealthMainStudRec, Line 38
Invalid column name 'HEALTHMAINSTUDRECID'.

(1 row(s) affected)`

Comment: check, if PS.HealthMainStudRec has column healthmainstudrecid.
check if HealthMainStudRec has column healthmainstudrecid

Comment: remove `end begin` before `insert into #SyncHealthMainStudRecTemp`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both database tables definitely have that column (healthmainstudrecid) - for the temporary one, it's created earlier in the procedure. I have removed the `end` and `begin` before the `insert`, I'm still getting the same error though.

Comment: Check Schema of HealthMainStudRec and add it in `MERGE INTO Schema.HealthMainStudRec`

Comment: The table is just under "dbo", trying it with the `dbo.` prefix yields the same error again.

Comment: See edit. This is the problem: CASE SENSITIVE collation

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... so basically I need all of the object names to match what they were originally in the Oracle DB?

Comment: #SyncHealthMainStudRecTemp has column names with uppercase. So everywere change to uppercase. Also check HealthMainStudRec and it's columns and call that columns as they are created.